# Distribution of norm of random matrix

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I am curious to know whether central-limit theorem like considerations hold true for special functions like the norm of a matrix.

Specifically, I'm interested in the [Spectral norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpectralNorm.html) of a matrix 
$$\|M^\prime\| = \text{Max eigenvalue of } (M^{\prime H}M^\prime),$$
where $(\bullet)^H$ represents the conjugate of the transpose of $(\bullet)$. Here, $M^\prime$ is close to matrix $M$ such that each element of ${M}^\prime$ has random error ${M}^\prime_{ij} = \mathcal{N}(M_{ij}, \sigma^2)$.

Question: **Will the distribution of $\|\tilde{M}\|$, which is a function of random variables $\tilde{M}_{ij}$ be a normal distribution?** I have tried to figure this out numerically. My numerics fit the normal distribution rather well. Is there a way to prove this analytically?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the answer with the Frobenius norm.

The Frobenius norm of a matrix squared is Chi-square. This follows from the fact that you are summing the diagonal entries squared. By equivalence of the **squared** Frobenius norm with the trace of the eigenvalue matrix, this also means that the sum of eigenvalues is Chi-square. By Cochran's Theorem, each quadratic form in contributing sum is also Chi-square. Therefore, by this reasoning, your maximum eigenvalue should be Chi-1 distributed.